# Getting value of parameter in xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am passing a parameter to an xsl template but it is not displaying its value there:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<information>
    <person>
        <name>John</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Joseph</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Ajay</name>
    </person>
</information>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
   <body>

   <xsl:call-template name="show_name">
     <xsl:with-param name="element" select=" 'hie' "/>
   </xsl:call-template>

   </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="show_name" match="/">
   <xsl:param name="element" />
   <xsl:for-each select="information/person">
     <p>Name: <xsl:value-of select="$element" /></p>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
Name:
Name:
Name:
```

where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two templates matching the document node `"/"`. This is considered an error in XSLT when two templates with equality priority match the same thing. What is probably happening is that your particular processor is not actually throwing an error, but always picking the second template to match "/", so the first template is not being used.

Your second template only needs to function as a named template anyway, so instead of doing this

```
 <xsl:template name="show_name" match="/">
```

Do this

```
<xsl:template name="show_name">
```